# JS Calendar: How Does it Set Date Highlight Color?

Tags: javascript

I'm tinkering with [JS Calendar](https://year-calendar.github.io/js-year-calendar/documentation) and I have this codepen example:

https://codepen.io/thecoderr254/pen/wvvJqaY

```
let tooltip = null;

const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
dataSource: function(year) {
    // Load data from GitHub API
    return fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:Paul-DS/bootstrap-year-calendar%20created:${year}-01-01..${year}-12-31`)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => {
        if (result.items) {
        return result.items.map(r => ({
            startDate: new Date(r.created_at),
            endDate: new Date(r.created_at),
        }));
        }

        return [];
    });
},
}).setStyle('background', 'red');
```

The interesting part is each "Date Range" has its own color code, this rule isn't set on the js or css code and I haven't seen a way to set that in the documentation.
A standard color is important in my case, preferably red to indicate a booked date.

Comment: If you take a look at line 624 through 652 of the source code for JS Calendar, you will see where the 'border' is set using a `box-shadow`: https://github.com/year-calendar/js-year-calendar/blob/master/src/ts/js-year-calendar.ts#L624

Comment: It appears that setting the 'border' style using `setStyle` on the element will influence the colour of the resuling `box-shadow`. See line 1338.

Comment: updated the description, adding style and background color still doesn't set the same color for all dates @Martin

Comment: The author of the github repo replied and showed me how it's done: https://github.com/year-calendar/js-year-calendar/issues/19#issuecomment-546449464